# Flyway deletes blocks of comments before the operation

Tags: sql-server, flyway

I have a alter procedure, with the default comments of MSSQL at the moment of creating it . Example:

```
USE [Database]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Example]    Script Date: 29-08- 
2018 9:38:54 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    -- =============================================
    -- Author:      <Author,,Name>
    -- Create date: <Create Date,,>
    -- Description: <Description,,>
    -- ============================================
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Example]
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
     -- HERE IS TSQL
    END
```

But when I run the command 
`flyway migrate` deletes the comments outside of the operations it detects. that is:

```
    -- =============================================
    -- Author:      <Author,,Name>
    -- Create date: <Create Date,,>
    -- Description: <Description,,>
    -- ============================================
```

The encode of my flyway is UTF-16LE .This because i have a problem with UTF-8. 
The problem is:

```
wrong syntax error near '?USE [Database]'.
```

But solve it by changing the encode to UTF-16LE.

The version of my flyway is: 5.1.4

The version of my MSSQL is: v17.5

Any solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: Both the encoding and the header comment should work. Please file two separate issues in the Flyway issue tracker, with clear steps how to reproduce.